# How do I mass relocate the iTunes library?

Tags: windows-7, itunes, nas

I have all the files in my iTunes library sitting on a NAS.  It is accessed via a Windows share.  I've changed my NAS last week and the new one exposes the data via a differently named share.  For example, files were previously in a `\\nas\A1Disk1` share, but are now in `\\nas\Disk1`.

Unfortunately there does not seem to be a way to change the name of the share.

How can I change my iTunes library to point to a new share without having to re-import everything?

iTunes is running in Windows 7 and it is set to NOT keep the Media folder organized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/articles/comments/moving-your-itunes-library-to-a-new-hard-drive/) helped me quite a lot in fully understanding the itunes libary concept. To make it short: Without commiting to letting iTunes organize the files it isn't possible. The problem is the difference between *referenced* and *managed-by-iTunes* files. If the files are completely managed by iTunes it can work quite well to change the Main folder even when migrating to OS X. But if they're only *referenced*, you're out of luck.