# Sharing iTunes library on a NAS with Windows and OS X machine

Tags: windows, macos, itunes, network-shares

I have a NAS system that I use to store music that is commonly accessed by a number of domestic PCs. We have also just bought a Mac using OS X Lion.

On the PCs I have mapped a drive letter to the NAS, so the music folder for all PC's is "Z/music" - and the various libraries in iTunes all use the network address with a the drive letter – so if I update the drive with new music from a PC and update that PC's Library file, I just copy that file to each of the other PC's and they are all updated too, since the music folder address is common.

However, although I can add the drive to the Mac and it can see the music file, it has its own network address and thus when I copy the new library file to the Mac – it does not understand the address. I know iTunes can do home sharing etc – but I really do not want to create a single iTunes account for the whole family – life is complicated enough with two teenagers and wife with their own Apple gadgets without trying to make them all conform to one apple account!

Any suggestions on how I could solve this?

Comment: I don't understand the "it has its own network address and thus when I copy the new library file to the Mac-it does not understand the address."  Could you elaborate or re-word?

Comment: @Josh Probably because there's no such thing as `Z:\music` on a Mac.

Comment: @slhck what is probably because...?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your mac doesn't work the same as the PCs in that you can't just copy the same network mapped folder to the mac's `~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/` folder.

Rather than "push" the library to the mac, I think you could just have the mac look for its library in a different (i.e., your NAS library) place.

With iTunes quit, hold down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key when starting up iTunes.  It will prompt you to choose the location of your Library.  You should be able to navigate to your NAS-stored iTunes music library and choose it.  iTunes will look in the same spot from then on.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could make a symlink/hardlink from the OS X iTunes Music folder to the network share. But as [I pointed out a little bit here](https://superuser.com/a/464118/153404) if you manage the file&folder structure yourself the files are considered as referenced instead of managed-by-itunes and iTunes cannot parse the backslashes from Windows ( \ ) instead of the slashes from OS X ( / ).

Further I suggest that you either move away from iTunes in your use-case or give up the idea of the shared music library for everyone. iTunes libraries are a personal thing; regarding the data iTunes collects and regarding the file management (the standard are music folders in a home directory).